# Prestashop multiple domain names

Tags: dns, prestashop, multiple-domains

I have a Prestashop store in www.theafricantouch.com.

I also have multiple domains pointing to the same DNS and same folder: .us, .fr, .de, .es, .co.uk, .net...

In the SEO and URLs configuration page of my prestashop backend, I set www.theafricantouch.com as the main store domain.

My goal is when an user from france uses theafricantouch.fr to visit my store, the browser always keep the .fr extension of the domain in the URL field.
Now, doesn't matter from where an user is entering, it always replaces the .fr, .es... extension with the .com

Is there any way to keep the extension?

Thanks,
Jonatan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "Multi Store" function, I'm sure you gonna find what you're looking for.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Managing+Multiple+Shops

Please notice all your domain should be with the same hoster or this solution won't work.